# Domsanitizer bypasssecuritytruststyle not working in ie 11

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, angular-dom-sanitizer

Html:- Here I set the style property from modalStyle which is in typescript

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="1000" [style]="modalStyle" >
```

component:- in typescript I use the domsanitizer to set the height,display,minheight, this works in chrome but not in ie 11. in ie 11 the height min-height and display is not set so the popup doesnt display.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export class Abc {
    get modalStyle() {
            return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('display:block; height:'
              + (this.modalDialog.nativeElement.clientHeight + 200) + 'px;'
              + 'min-height:1500' + '' + 'px;');
          }
        }
       }
```

Comment: have the same problem: works in both Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11. Did you find any solution/workaround since?

Comment: I have the same issue too.. does anyone have any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this polyfill:

```
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.15/polyfillsIE.min.js></script>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.